# How to fix not appearing lights in Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, lighting

Developing a simple zombie game with day-night cycle. So, for the player to handle the night, i am making a flashlight. Modeled it, and i need a real Unity light to make it a flashlight (but it's anyways flashlight, but broken..?). The light works neither in Scene or Game window. Here i'll show you some screenshots (and a [test video](https://youtu.be/LAzL-FNaTiA)):
[image: Scene view]
[image: Game view]

I tried clearing cache, as i found on Internet, but it only worked until i switched tabs.

## EDIT for @BugFinder [30.01.2023]

Light component for the flashlight:

[image: Light component settings]

*Switching between Point and Spot light isn't doing anything.*

Comment: Have you tried increasing the range and intensity of the light source?

Comment: Please share your light settings for the torch

Comment: @QBruteYes, i have.

Comment: @QBrute The light settings are now in the body of the question. Take a look.

Comment: Intensity of 1 and Range of 3 seems pretty low. That's what I meant, have you tried settings these values to something high? Also I've noticed that the mode is set to "Baked". Try "Realtime".

Comment: Yes your light should not be set to baked if it is supposed to work dynamically on runtime ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your light mode is currently set to `Baked`. This instructs Unity to prerender a static light when you press bake lighting in the lighting menu. Obviously you don't want something static for your flashlight, so change the mode to `Realtime`.